# My React Native app doesn't run

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, ubuntu-16.04, expo

I built a react native app, connected with Firebase, with expo libraries in Ubuntu 16.0.4. I was trying to implement the Facebook authentication through firebase so I built a parallel "Test App" where the authentication worked. Then, when I want to implement this code in my original app I get this error en Expo XDE:

Error Expo XDE

[image]

I run npm install first and when I run "npm ls" I get this in terminal:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.6.1, required by react-native-modal-popover@0.0.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-native@^0.45.1, required by react-native-modal-popover@0.0.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@>=15.3.1, required by lottie-react-native@1.1.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@>=15.4.0, required by react-native-branch@2.0.0-beta.3
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@>= 16.0.0, required by react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.0-alpha.14
```

I tried to install the versions of the dependencies that are shown in the screen but, for example, when I install "react@15.6.1" I get dependencies error for "react@16", and It is like this with other dependencies. What can I do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you might be using an older version of React Native (given that one of the errors is because you need at least React Native 0.45.1, and the current latest is 0.51), but that some other dependencies require a very recent version of React (16.0.0), so it's likely just unable to reconcile all of those requirements.

Best bet, if at all possible, would be to upgrade to the latest React Native (0.51), and then update your React dependency also to the one that RN 0.51 depends upon, 16.0.0. They should play nicely together, and hopefully work with all your other dependencies by the looks of things too. You'll then need to test your app functionality to make sure the upgrade hasn't broken anything of course.

The dependencies list for React and RN in your package.json should look like the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0"
},
```

Give that a go, hope that helps!